# I get error 1004 when closing excel files without macro

Tags: excel, vba

> Problem: I am having an issue with a Error 1004 "Application-defined or Object-defined error" when closing a excel file.

1. Version, Product Info: Microsoft Excel 2008, MS 365 Apps for Enterprise
2. Extra Info: i dont use macro

i need your suggestions.
kind regards,

Comment: Do you have any add-ins installed/active?

Comment: Yes, after the read your question, i tried to disabled and enabled all excel add-ins. problem solved but i couldnt understand to reason.

thanks for inspiring